# Controle de quebra de linha não funciona "white-space: nowrap:"

Tags: html, css

Não sei onde estou errando, porém a 5° barra da sequencia numérica, não quer se alinhar de forma linear, mesmo dando um float:left; e um "nowrap"  pois quero adicionar uma barra de rolagem inferior no conteúdo, mas apenas a barra lateral é adicionada, se eu aumentar a largura da 'div' principal consequentemente não haverá quebra de linha, porém a barra de rolagem inferior não é exibida, como faço para exibir uma barra inferior conforme a largura definida na 'div' .menu,??

```css
body{background-color:#6C9;}
.menu{ overflow:auto;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width:500px;  
  height:300px; 
}
.menu > div{ float:left; 
  height:340px; 
  margin-left:5px; 
  width:100px; 
  background-color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua o `float:left` por `display:inline-block` nas divs internas

```css
body{
    background-color:#6C9;
}
.menu { 
  overflow:auto;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width:500px;  
  height:300px; 
}
.menu > div { 
  display: inline-block; 
  height:340px; 
  margin-left:5px; 
  width:100px; 
  background-color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use esse css:

body{background-color:#6C9;}
.menu{ overflow:scroll;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width:500px;
  height:300px; 
}
.menu > div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:340px; 
  margin-left:5px; 
  width:100px; 
  background-color:#FFF;
}

o problema estava com o float que deixa todos para o lado esquerdo.

Comment: Não serve também, a 5° barra está dando quebra de linha ao diminuir a largura no '.menu' queria deixar todas as barras de forma alinhadas horizontalmente e exibir um scrool inferior, pois quanto mais eu diminuo a largura do '.menu' mais haverá  quebra de linha, porém não quero que isso aconteça